# std::string vs const std::string& vs std::string_view

Tags: c++

Что правильнее передавать как аргумент функции(например в конструктор), если там эта строка будет просто скопирована?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование любого из альтернативных средств очень сильно зависит от ситуации, и выбирается исходя из конкретных условий. И это относится не только к `std::string` и `std::string_view`

Для начала определимся с реализацией наших сущностей. Пусть `std::string` построен на трех указателях по 4 байта каждый (или указатель и два размера):

```
class string
{
    //...
    pointer * m_begin;          //Начало строки
    pointer * m_end;            //Указатель за последний элемент
    pointer * m_end_of_storage; //Указатель за конец выделенной памяти
};
```

`std::string_view` при этом реализован с помощью двух указателей (или указатель и размер):

```
class string_view
{
    //...
    pointer m_data; //Указатель на начало данных
    pointer m_end;  //Указатель за конец данных
};
```

Упрощенно рассмотрим три версии простого кода:

```
void other(std::string); //<-- функция, в которую всегда передается копия.

void run(string_view v) //<-- Функция, которая вызывает функцию other
{
    //т.е. эта функция делает ту самую копию объекта
    other(v);
}  

void general(string str)
{
    //А из этой функции в функцию run передается строка
    other(str);
}
```

Что будет сгенерировано компилятором и как рассматривать не будем, т.к. это сильно зависит от компилятора и параметров компиляции, но постараемся посмотреть что может быть и как.

В нашем случае `other` передает копию `string_view`, т.е. `general` копирует два указателя (не говорим о возможности вызова конструктора копирования, подразумевая, что он самый тривиальный и в результирующем коде приведет просто к копированию двух членов класса). Затем строка копируется из `string_view`. Ничего сложного.

Теперь возьмем тот же код, но при этом run будет принимать ссылку на `string`.

```
void run(string const & v)
{
    other(v);
}  

void general(string str)
{
    other(str);
    //str используется, её нельзя перемещать в other
}
```

Да, Вы правы, передача ссылки в функцию `run` - быстрая операция, можно считать, что это копирование указателя. Но у передачи ссылки есть и минусы. Один из них - функция `run` обращается к строке через ссылку, т.е. появляется дополнительный уровень косвенности, который может вылиться в большие затраты, чем "лишнее" копирование указателя в версии функции, принимающей `string_view`.

Теперь рассмотрим третий вариант функции `run`:

```
void run(string v)
{
    other(std::move(v));
}
```

В данном случае копирование строки происходит еще в функции `general` (причем мы не перемещаем параметр `str`, т.к. он где-то там еще нужен далее). Затем функция `run` перемещает объект `v` в параметр функции `other`, а это в нашем случае приводит к копированию трех указателей и занулению старых. Очевидно, что в этом случае операций намного больше, чем со `string_view`, и, вполне вероятно, что косвенное обращение будет тоже быстрее. То есть это может быть самым тормознутым вариантом.

А теперь представим, такую ситуацию:

```
void run(string const &); //<-- имеется такая run
void run(string_view); //или такая, нам без разницы

class SomeClass 
{
    string m_text;
    mutex m_mutex;
    void SomeClass::call()
    {            
        //Мы знаем, что run делает копию строки,
        //и запускает поток для её обработки            
        lock_quard<mutex> locker;//объект у нас защищен мьютексом
        run(m_text);//Где-то там строка копируется и запускается новый поток
        //мы не знаем точный момент, когда строка скопируется, 
        //поэтому вынуждены ждать выполнения run под защитой мьютекса, 
        //т.к. в other содержаться указатели на защищенные члены нашего класса.
        //Вполне вероятно, что в этот момент другие 
        //потоки уже хотят работать с нашим объектом, 
        //но не могут, т.к. мьютекс захвачен.
    }
};
```

Я в комментариях описал проблему. А теперь возьмем ситуацию с копированием и перемещением:

```
void run(string); //<-- теперь run принимает копию

class SomeClass 
{
    //..
    void SomeClass::call()
    {            
        //Мы знаем, что run принимает копию строки
        //и запускает поток для её обработки    
        unique_lock<mutex> locker;//объект у нас защищен мьютексом
        string text_copy = m_text;//Под защитой выполняем копирование строки
        locker.unlock();//И разблокируем мьютекс, т.к.
        run(std::move(text_copy));//нам уже без разницы что-том делает run,
        //копия данных для него уже создана и другим потокам можно дать доступ к объекту
    }
};
```

У `string_view` при этом тоже имеются свои прелести. `string_view` в принципе не привязан к `string` - это просто данные и их размер. Т.е. `string_view` может работать не только с `string`:

```
void run(string_view v);

void general(string str)
{
    other(str);//ok
}

void general(char const * str, size_t len)
{
    other(string_view(str, len));//ok
}

void general(char const * str)
{
    other(string_view(str));//ok
}

void general(std::vector<char> const & v)
{
    other(string_view(v.data(), v.size()));//ok
}
```

В случае передачи ссылки придется сделать лишнюю копию строки, в случае передачи копии строки это не страшно, т.к. копия будет перемещена, но это всё равно может быть дороже. Однако, копия строки с перемещением может быть дешевле `string_view`, если, например для создания `string_view` потребуется сначала создать строку или какой-то другой буфер с данными. В таком случае будет лучше создать строку и переместить её.

Но оптимизации также могут перевернуть всё с ног на голову. Когда нужно сделать копию строки, кажется, что это приведет к аллокации памяти и всё это будет медленно. В общем случае это верно, но есть такая штука, как SSO (small string optimization), которая позволяет хранить маленькие строки прямо в объекте `string`, используя сам объект как буфер для строки. В случае применения такой оптимизации копирование может оказаться равноценно или даже дешевле перемещения.

То есть создав копию в вызывающей функции и переместив строку в вызываемую функцию, Вы если и потеряете скорость, то очень немного. Но это всё относится к ситуации, когда нужна копия на вызываемой стороне. Если же копия не нужна, то вариантов также масса.

> а для чего тогда стоит использовать string_view?

`string_view` **нужен как раз тогда, когда копия строки не нужна**, но нужно сослаться на какое-то место и с ним работать как со строкой. Ранее нужно было либо писать свою "обертку" подобную `string_view`, либо копировать нужные данные из исходной строки и работать с ними.

Всё сказанное выше весьма условно и служит только для демонстрации различных ситуаций.

Как видите, применение того или иного средства полностью зависит от конкретных условий использования, применяемых алгоритмов, оптимизаций компилятора, устройства библиотеки, платформы на которой всё это работает и т.д., поэтому закончу тем, с чего начал - использование любого из альтернативных средств очень сильно зависит от ситуации, и выбирается исходя из конкретных условий.

Answer (score 4):

Просто `std::string`. А потом вместо компирования - перемещать через `std::move`.

Comment: а для чего тогда стоит использовать string_view? И чем это лучше чем константная ссылка, с ней то по идее будет вызван только copy конструктор

Comment: это всё весьма и весьма сомнительно.

Comment: @timbars *"чем это лучше"* Тем, что при таком варианте мы можем в некоторых случаях избежать копирования - когда передаем в функцию временный объект (rvalue). `string_view`, имхо, нужен для функций, анализирующих строки или сегменты строк (при парсинге и т. п.). Как универсальный "параметр-строка" он не особо прижился, имхо, потому что часто требудется, чтобы параметр был null-terminated, чего `string_view` не дает.

Comment: @Croessmah Расска́жите подробнее?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, зачем требуется null-terminated строка? Это бесполезный анахронизм.

Comment: @ixSci В первую очередь для работы с С-библиотеками.

Comment: Ну, это довольно специфичный, хоть и распространённый случай. В контексте вопроса данный аспект не затрагивается, поэтому я бы на стал рассуждать в терминах null-terminated string. А вот вариант std::string -> move просто по всем параметрам хуже банального `std::string_view`, опять же в контексте данного вопроса.

Comment: @ixSci *"по всем параметрам хуже"* ТС ведь всегда копирует строку-параметр, а мы таким способом избавляемся от копирования для rvalue. Разве это не плюс?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, почему избавляемся? Если передать `"smthng"`, то для string будет создан временный объект, а для `string_view` — нет. Я вообще не вижу варианта, при котором для `string_view` будет больше работы.

Comment: @ixSci Пусть имеем некоторую `std::string foo();`. Если сделать `void bar(std::string x) {my_string = std::move(x);} ... bar(foo());`, то копирования не будет вообще. А если сделать `void bar(std::string_view x) {my_string = x;} ... bar(foo());`, то копирование будет, что для длинных строк плохо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, принимается, только это опять какой-то высосанный из пальца пример, с моей точки зрения. На моей практике в функции куда чаще передаются либо lvalue, либо C-строки.

Answer (score 2):

1. Если строка будет "просто скопирована", то вам следует реализовывать либо "ленивый" вариант семантики перемещения (передавать `std::string` по значению и затем делать из него перемещение), либо "полный" вариант семантики перемещения (писать две перегруженных функции: для `const std::string &` и для `std::string &&`), либо, возможно, реализовать forwarding (писать шаблонную функцию, принимающую универсальную сслыку и делающую `std::forward` в вашу копию).

   См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/822789/182825
2. `std::string_view` уместен везде, где вы будете просто анализировать строку, т.е. он является заменителем `const std:string &` в ситуациях, когда копирование не будет делаться.