# Явная копия в copy-and-swap

Tags: c++, ссылки, оператор-присваивания

Смотрю в википедии на [описание copy-and-swap](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B)#.D0.98.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B0) и [его же в отдельной статье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-and-swap):

```
RFive& operator=(const RFive& other)
{
    Rfive tmp(other);
    swap (*this, tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

Мне интересно, зачем создавать копию явно внутри метода

```
RFive& operator=(const RFive& other)
{
    Rfive tmp(other);
```

если можно создать копию неявно просто передав аргумент по значению (т. е. без ссылки)

```
RFive& operator=(RFive other)
```

У этого варианта есть какие-то скрытые недостатки?

---

Я бы вообще как-то так сделал:

```
RFive & operator = (RFive other)
{
    return this->operator=(std::move(other));
}
```

Нормально? Естественно, только для случая, когда есть

```
RFive & operator = (RFive &&other)
```

Comment: По-моему, Саттер писал о равноценности обоих вариантов...

Comment: Нет, нету. Типичная реализация делается именно с передачей по значению. Если учесть, что константная lvalue ссылка привязывается *напрямую* к объекту, указуемеому rvalue ссылкой, разницы быть не должно.

Comment: А зачем ```const``` в последнем блоке кода? Или Вы просто забыли его убрать?

Comment: @isnullxbh, забыл удалить, уже убрал. И вопрос немного дополнил.

Comment: У вас какая-то бесконечная рекурсия в последнем примере. Что вы хотели сказать последним примером? Почему из `operator =` вызывается опять этот же `operator =`?

Comment: @AnT, не рекурсия, вызываться должен `RFive& operator=(RFive&& other)` за счёт `std::move` - разве нет?

Comment: Copy-and-swap idiom нужна в том числе именно для того, чтобы одним оператором (!) покрыть и сopy, и move семантику. Зачем вам писать еще и `operator=(RFive&& other)`??? Не надо этого делать. Просто внутри вашего `operator = (RFive other)` ручками *перемещайте* содержимое `other` в `*this`.

Comment: @AnT, а зачем в википедии написали? Вроде бы они на этом операцию копирования экономят перед свопом. Если у нас уже rvalue ref, то можно свопать прямо с ним.

Comment: В википедии вариант с  `(const RFive& other)`! Либо два метода: `(const RFive& other)` и `(RFive&& other)`, либо один `(RFive other)`. Много раз уже об этом писали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/822789/182825

Comment: Да нет, вроде бы именно копирования: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azysh.png

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92272/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-ant).

Comment: @AnT "*Зачем вам писать еще и operator=(RFive&& other)*?" - чтобы избегать создания временных объектов когда можно обойтись без них.

Comment: @VTT: В такой ситуации - если вы хотите достичь максимальной эффективности - вам нужно писать пару `const &` и `&&`. Пара из "по значению" и `&&` некорректна, ибо будет вызывать ошибку перегрузки при вызове с `std::move`.

Comment: @AnT Так в том-то и проблема, что с `operator = (RFive other)` от лишнего объекта никак не избавиться.

Comment: @VTT: Совершенно верно. Потому я и говорю - у вас есть "ленивый" вариант реализации - с `operator = (RFive other)` - который в контексте перемещения создает один лишний временный объект и делает для него одно лишнее перемещение. Но в 9 случаях из 10 это - приемлемо. И элегантность покрытия copy и move **одним** оператором того стоит. А если вам где-то важна максимальная эффективность, то тогда вам придется писать `operator = (const RFive &other)` и `operator = (RFive &&other)` по отдельности.

Comment: Развёрнутый [ответ](http://scrutator.me/post/2018/07/30/value_vs_reference.aspx) по теме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комбинация

```
RFive& operator=(RFive other)
RFive& operator=(RFive &&other)
```

о которой вы ведете речь, нежизнеспособна вообще. Такой вариант будет приводить к неоднозначности overload resolution при вызове с `std::move` в качестве аргумента (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ae64b244f99d5f7)

В остальном ваш вопрос по сути является дупликатом [Захват аргументов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822759/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

У вас на выбор есть два варианта достаточно эффективной поддержки присваивания с учетом move semantics.

1. Либо писать две версии оператора

   ```
   RFive& operator=(const RFive &other)
   {
     // copy from `other`
   }

   RFive& operator=(RFive &&other)
   {
     // move from `other`
   }
   ```
2. Либо - "ленивый" вариант - только одну версию

   ```
   RFive& operator=(RFive other)
   {
     // move from `other`
   }
   ```

   Эта единственная версия во втором варианте покрывает функциональность обеих версий оператора из первого варианта, но с небольшим(?) накладным расходом - один дополнительный промежуточный объект и один дополнительный move в контексте перемещения.

Второй вариант - предпочтительнее в большинстве случаев, когда вам не нужно выжимать из кода какие-то процессорные такты, ибо просто позволяет писать меньше кода.

Answer (score 1):

У этого варианта есть два радикальных недостатка - создание и разрушение передаваемого объекта будет каждый раз вставляться в код, который вызывает эту функцию, а не один раз в теле самой функции. Это особенно плохо, если класс импортируется из динамической библиотеки. Временный объект создается всегда, даже в ситуации, когда его создания можно было бы избежать при использовании раздельных копирующего и перемещающего конструктора `RFive five{}; other = ::std::move(five);`

Comment: Т. е. увеличение объёма кода? А каких-нибудь плюсов от возможной оптимизации нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy О какого рода оптимизации идет речь? Мне такой способ как раз представляется анти оптимизацией.